# facebook realtime subsciption API error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time, payment

I'm using this link in order to add new subsciption entry:

https://graph.facebook.com/XXX/subscriptions?access_token=YYY&object=payments&callback_url=http://xxx/rlcallback.php&fields=actions,disputes&verify_token=ZZZ

```
For some reason, I get error:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Invalid object. object should be url or open graph object id.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

But the object "payments" inside my link is clearly valid. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct parameters: object, callback_url, fields, verify_token...and of course the access_token.

Also (and that may be the problem in this case), **you have to use POST, not GET**. You can either use [CURL](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php) with POST to subscribe to the Realtime API, or you just use one of the SDKs as explained in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/subscriptions

Here is one example with CURL:

```php
$appsecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', FBAPPID . '|' . FBSECRET, FBSECRET);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'facebook-php');
$postData = 'object=page' .
    '&callback_url=' . urlencode('http://yourdomain.com/callback.php') .
    '&fields=feed' .
    '&verify_token=somethingfancy' .
    '&access_token=' . FBAPPID . '|' . FBSECRET .
    '&appsecret_proof=' . $appsecretProof;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . FBAPPID . '/subscriptions');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify object, callback_url, fields and verify_token parameters as your curl post parameters

example:
    curl -F 'object=user' \
    -F 'callback_url=' \
    -F 'fields=checkins' \
    -F 'verify_token=' \
    "https://graph.facebook.com//subscriptions?access_token=